# Why aren't these additions of integrals and summations equal?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, simplifying-expressions

I have the following code:

```
 Simplify[Integrate[f[x] + g[x], x] == Integrate[f[x], x] + Integrate[g[x], x]]
```

To test:

$$\int{\left(f(x) + g(x)\right)dx}=\int{f(x)dx}+\int{g(x)dx}$$

Why doesn't this simplify to `True`?  More importantly, how can I get this to evaluate to `True`?  I'm going through some manipulations of equations, and I'd like to use *Mathematica* to doublecheck my math and help with it.

I run into the same problem with `Sum`, where `Integrate` in the previous equation can be replaced by `Sum`.  I'm using *Mathematica* 8.0.4.0.

Comment: I found that adding `d[`expression `,x]` with `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` will evaluate to true.  In other words, I am taking the derivative of the expression, and that seems to eliminate the integrals.  I'd like to know if there are other workarounds, though.  The new code is: `FullSimplify[
 D[Integrate[a[x] + b[x], x] == 
   Integrate[a[x], x] + Integrate[b[x], x], x]]`

Comment: Why do you need any workarounds ?  Your last issue with `FullSimplify` is just an inconsequence of `M`. Look at `Integrate[a[x] + b[x], x]`, `Integrate[a[x], x]` and, all they return the results as the integrals would actually exist, moreover as they would be differentiable. While that is not correct in general.

Comment: @Artes: I was just wondering if there are any related features available.  What did you mean by `M`?

Comment: `M` like `Mathematica`.  I meant it wasn't a good feature of `M` when it returned `True` in that case. Look that you need not `FullSimplify` to get `True`, evaluate that expression without `FullSimplify`. It shouldn't return `True`, unless you assume `a[x]` to be integrable/ differentiable e.g. `a[x_]:=x^2`. There are many imperfect issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the issue in the question.

`Mathematica` shouldn't evaluate

```
Simplify[ Integrate[f[x] + g[x], x] == Integrate[f[x], x] + Integrate[g[x], x]]
```

to `True`, because in general such a rule would be mathematically simply wrong.

Consider e.g. $ \forall_{x  } f(x) = - g(x)$,  while $f$ is not e.g. Lesbegue integrable. Of course `Mathematica` does not distinguish integrability subtleties, nevertheless there should be

```
Integrate[f[x] + g[x], x] == 0
```

while $\int{f(x)dx}$ and $\int{g(x)dx}$   don't not exist.   Q.E.D

One should emphasize that the rule works well if we define appropriate integrable functions, e.g.

```
f[x_] := x^3 + 2 x + 1
g[x_] := Hypergeometric1F1[3, 7, x]
Simplify[ Integrate[ f[x] + g[x], x] == Integrate[ f[x], x] + Integrate[ g[x], x]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Edit**

If there is a need for a rule distributing integrals over a sum of functions (knowing that we can do this in an appropriate class of functions) we could define an adequate rule, e.g.

```
intRule = Integrate[a_ + b_, c_] :> Integrate[a, c] + Integrate[b, c];
```

and use it with [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html?q=ReplaceRepeated&lang=en) (`//.`)

```
( Integrate[ f[x] + g[x] + h[x], x] //. intRule ) == 
  Integrate[f[x], x] + Integrate[g[x], x] + Integrate[h[x], x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

in the traditional form it yields :

```
Integrate[ f[x] + g[x] + h[x], x] //. intRule // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

To get the behaviour you want, you can tell `Simplify` to try distributing `Integrate` over `Plus` as one of its transformations:

```
Simplify[Integrate[f[x] + g[x], x] == Integrate[f[x], x] + Integrate[g[x], x], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. i_Integrate :> Distribute[i] &}]
```

> True