# How to expand terms within an integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why aren’t these additions of integrals and summations equal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/why-arent-these-additions-of-integrals-and-summations-equal)

I am trying to expand all the terms in a sum in order to apply assignment rules later, but can't figure out how to do it. I've tried pretty much the commands I've seen around here.
I have the following integral:

$$\iint(x^2+y^2) f(x,y)dxdy$$

and I would like to extend it to

$$\iint x^2 f(x,y)dxdy+\iint y^2 f(x,y)dxdy$$

in order to apply rules like $\iint x^2f(x,y)dxdy \to a$ and so on. I would like to do this in a generic way since the integrand would not always look like the one in the example here. Any idea?

Comment: Look at a related problem : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/why-arent-these-additions-of-integrals-and-summations-equal

Comment: Please look at the link that Artes posted, which explains why such an expansion would be wrong in general and also a way to do it nevertheless. This is a duplicate of that question and will be closed as such @Artes, please vote to close instead of flagging, since you have the rep to do it :)

Comment: Thanks, I still can't make it work but I'll look through it a bit more and comment in said post if needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Finally managed to make it work, I didn't know one had to be so careful defining the exact rules.