# Equation Simplification in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I wonder if the following equation could be further simplified by Mathematica. There are $22$ Integrals involved and many of them are in the range $y_l$ and $y_u$. I would guess that at least those terms could be collected in the same integral. I used the command FullSimplify but the result is the same with the input. Are there some more clever ways to simplify such type of equations?

```
(2*(1 - \[Epsilon]0)^2*Integrate[((Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]
*l[yu]])*(-Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yl]] + Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[l[yu]])^2, {y, yl, yu}] - 2*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*(-Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]]), {y, yl, yu}] +
 Integrate[f0[y], {y, -Infinity, yl}]*Sqrt[l[yl]])*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*
 (Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]]), 
{y, yl, yu}] + Integrate[f0[y], {y, yu, Infinity}]*Sqrt[l[yu]]) -
 Sqrt[(-2*(1 - \[Epsilon]0)^2*Integrate[((Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]])*(-Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yl]] +
 Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]])^2, {y, yl, yu}] + 
2*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*(-Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]]), {y, yl, yu}] + 
Integrate[f0[y], {y, -Infinity, yl}]*Sqrt[l[yl]])*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*
(Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[l[yu]]), {y, yl, yu}] + Integrate[f0[y], {y, yu, Infinity}]*
Sqrt[l[yu]]))^2 - 4*((Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*(-Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]]), {y, yl, yu}] +
 Integrate[f0[y], {y, -Infinity, yl}]*Sqrt[l[yl]])^2 - 
(1 -\[Epsilon]0)^2*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*(-Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]])^2)/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]])^2, {y, yl, yu}] + 
Integrate[f0[y], {y, -Infinity, yl}]*l[yl]))*((Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*
(Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + 
Sqrt[l[yu]]), {y, yl, yu}] + Integrate[f0[y], {y, yu, Infinity}]*
Sqrt[l[yu]])^2 - (1 - \[Epsilon]0)^2*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]])^2/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]])^2, {y, yl, yu}] + 
Integrate[f0[y], {y, yu, Infinity}]*l[yu]))])/(2*((Integrate[(Sqrt[f0[y]]*
(Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]]))/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]]), 
{y, yl, yu}] + Integrate[f0[y], {y, yu, Infinity}]*Sqrt[l[yu]])^2 - 
(1 - \[Epsilon]0)^2*(Integrate[(Sqrt[f1[y]*l[yu]] - 
Sqrt[f0[y]*l[yl]*l[yu]])^2/(-Sqrt[l[yl]] + Sqrt[l[yu]])^2, {y, yl, yu}] 
+Integrate[f0[y], {y, yu, Infinity}]*l[yu])))
```

Comment: How about trying two of them first? If that works, then go to three...

Comment: @bills thanks for the comment. There are $22$ but they are not in the form of simple summations. Sometimes multiplications and some times in the phranthesis etc. Please have a look at it via printing the equations. Seemed complicated to deal one by one to me.

Comment: There is a quite dirty four letters word for this kind of thing. It's called "work"

Comment: @belisarius lets dont call it as dirty. It is usually what we usually do.. This formula is also a result of such long series of dirty algebra by hand. Then I had to give it to mathematica, because i had to find the roots of a polynomial of degree $2$. The result is as above. Now which is dirtier? trying to write these equations back to papers and try to reduce by hand or try to find a way in mathematica so that a simplification can be done. I think both)

Comment: To be or not to be ...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your expression is `expr`. Then you can parse this this way, first let's take a look at a structure of the `expr`, in order to do this we can create a list of substititutions. Of course we are doing this because we have seen that there are common terms involving integrals:

```
 (subs = With[{set = Cases[expr, _Integrate, ∞] // DeleteDuplicates},
           Table[set[[i]] :> Evaluate@int[i], {i, Length@set}]]

  ) // Grid[{#}\[Transpose], Alignment -> Right, BaseStyle -> {18}] &
```

> [image]

```
expr /. subs
```

> [image]

If you take a closer look you can see that there are no terms that could be collected inside common integral.

Even if there would be it can be tough according to [Why aren't these additions of integrals and summations equal?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8353/5478)

So as you can see `FullSimplify` is not enough to do this. (*in the case where it can be done*) Distributing `Integrate` is quite easy and is shown in the linked answer. If you want to gather terms to the common `Integrate` you can try with the following pattern:

```
5 Integrate[f[x], {x, x1, x2}] - 2 Integrate[g[x], {x, x1, x2}] //. (
  con1_. Integrate[a_, {x_, l__}] + con2_. Integrate[b_, {x_, l__}]) :> 
  Integrate[con1 a + con2 b, {x, l}] /; D[con1, x] == 0 && D[con2, x] == 0
```

> [image]

Comment: thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören That's great you find it useful :) Good luck!