# Let mathematica combine integral limits

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

Is there a way to teach mathematica to combine integral limits according to $\int_a^b f dx+\int_b^c f dx=\int_a^cf dx$ to simplify expressions like $\int_0^1 f[t] dt+\int_1^x (1+f[t]) dt$ to $\int_0^t f[t] dt+x-1$ ? Additionally, it'll be helpful for mathematica to know $-\int_b^a f dx+\int_b^c f dx=\int_a^cf dx$ is equvalent to $\int_a^b f dx+\int_b^c f dx=\int_a^cf dx$.

Comment: You might tackle this by designing a `ComplexityFunction` for `Simplify` ..  ( search this site I think you might find some similar examples )

Comment: Im sorry, it is `TransformationFunctions` you want, see here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/why-arent-these-additions-of-integrals-and-summations-equal/8359#8359

Comment: @george2079 Excellent! Problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for TagSetDelayed I believe:

```
Unprotect@Integrate;
Integrate /: 
  Plus[Integrate[ft_, {t_, a_, b_}], Integrate[ft_, {t_, b_, c_}]] := 
  Integrate[ft, {t, a, c}];
Integrate /: 
  Plus[Integrate[ft_, {t_, b_, a_}], Integrate[ft_, {t_, b_, c_}]] := 
  Integrate[ft, {t, a, c}];
Protect@Integrate;
```

But be careful when you unprotect system functions...

Comment: Thanks! It works for `Integrate[f[t], {t, a, b}] + Integrate[f[t], {t, b, c}]` but not `-Integrate[f[t], {t, b, a}] + Integrate[f[t], {t, b, c}]`.

Comment: @davidsedai I added a rule for that, you can keep adding them for other cases if you want...

Answer (score 1):

One may also use `Inactivate/Activate`construct. For example, try this

```
expr = Inactivate[
  Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, 2}], Integrate]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Then make the replacement:

```
    expr /. Inactivate[
   Integrate[g_, {x, a_, b_}] + Integrate[g_, {x, b_, c_}], 
   Integrate] -> Inactivate[Integrate[g, {x, a, c}], Integrate]
```

giving this:

[image]

Then let us activate the result:

```
 % // Activate
```

returning this:

[image]

Let us also check it with a certain function `f[x]`, say, with `x^2`:

```
 expr1 = Inactivate[
  Integrate[x^2, {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[x^2, {x, 1, 2}], Integrate]
```

[image]

```
expr1 /. Inactivate[
   Integrate[g_, {x, a_, b_}] + Integrate[g_, {x, b_, c_}], 
   Integrate] -> Inactivate[Integrate[g, {x, a, c}], Integrate]
```

[image]

```
   % // Activate

(*  8/3 *)
```

Have fun!