# simplifying integrals for multiple exponentials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/why-arent-these-additions-of-integrals-and-summations-equal/), but applied to products of `Exp[]`. For example, I have a symbolic expression containing terms like

$Exp[\int_0^1 f[t]dt](c_1 Exp[\int_1^s f[t]dt]+c_2Exp[-\int_s^1 f[t]dt])$

obtained straight from `DSolve[]` and `FullSimplify[]`. How to teach mathematica that the expression can be simplified to

$(c_1+c_2)Exp[\int_0^s f[t] dt]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica evidently won't simplify

```
Integrate[f[t], {t, a, b}] + Integrate[f[t], {t, b, c}]
```

to

```
Integrate[f[t], {t, a, c}]
```

on its own. However, you can easily write a function that does what you want, by using Mathematica's ability to have functions do pattern matching on their arguments. Here's a function that will do what we want:

```
simplifier[Integrate[f_[t_], {t_, tmin_, tmax_}] + Integrate[f_[u_], {u_, tmax_, s_}]] :=  
  Integrate[f[t], {t, tmin, s}];
simplifier[Integrate[f_[t_], {t_, tmin_, tmax_}] - Integrate[f_[u_], {u_, s_, tmax_}]] :=  
  Integrate[f[t], {t, tmin, s}];
```

This may not be 100% robust against corner cases, but it will definitely do what we want in this instance. We can then pass this function to `Simplify` (or `FullSimplify`) using the [`TransformationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) option, like so:

```
term = Exp[Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]]*
        (c[1] Exp[Integrate[f[t], {t, 1, s}]] + c[2] Exp[-Integrate[f[t], {t, s, 1}]])

Simplify[term, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, simplifier}] // InputForm
```

> ```
> E^Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, s}]*(c[1] + c[2])
> ```

Putting `Automatic` in the list of `TransformationFunctions` tells `Simplify` to use all of its normal transformations in addition to our additional function `simplifier`.