# Simplify complex answer given by DSolve[]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I tried the technique in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76930/simplifying-integrals-for-multiple-exponentials), but that did not work for the solution given by
the MWE:

```
DSolve[{f'[t] + f[t]*g[t] == h[t], f[0] == f0}, {f[t]}, t]
```

How to teach Mathematica to simplify the solution to $\int_0^t h(s) \exp \left(-\int_s^t g(\tau ) \, d\tau \right) \, ds+f0\exp \left(-\int_0^t g(s) \, ds\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html):

```
Clear[xf];
xf[e_] := 
  e /. {Integrate[int_, {x_, a_, b_}] - Integrate[int_, {x_, a_, c_}] :>
          Integrate[int, {x, c, b}],
        coeff_ Integrate[int_, {x_, a_, b_}] :> 
          Integrate[coeff int, {x, a, b}]};

sol = DSolve[{f'[t] + f[t]*g[t] == h[t], f[0] == f0}, {f[t]}, t];
Simplify[sol, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {xf, Expand, Collect[#, Power[E, _]] &, Automatic}]
(*
  {{f[t] -> E^Integrate[-g[K[1]], {K[1], 0, t}] * f0 +
             Integrate[E^Integrate[-g[K[1]], {K[1], K[2], t}]*h[K[2]], {K[2], 0, t}]}}
*)
```

To get the answer in the form requested (it's not "simpler" according to the default [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) of [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html):

```
% /. {Integrate[int_, {x_, t, b_}] :> -Integrate[int, {x, b, t}]} /.
      {K[1] -> s, K[2] -> τ}

(*
  {{f[t] -> E^Integrate[-g[s], {s, 0, t}] * f0 + 
           Integrate[E^Integrate[-g[s], {s, τ, t}] * h[τ], {τ, 0, t}]}}
*)
```

Comment: Using the code in your first block does not give a very good result because strictly speaking `E^Integrate[g[K[1]], {K[1], t, K[2]}]` includes the integrate index `K[2]` and should be included in the last `Integrate[h[K[2]], {K[2], 0, t}]`. Following your idea, the second replace rule in `xf` function should be `coeff_*Integrate[int_,{x_, a_, b_}] :> Integrate[coeff*int,{x, a, b}]`

Comment: @egwenesedai Of course -- and thanks!  (Fixed now, I hope.)