# Use Mathematica to derive the probability distributions using the Principle of Maximum Entropy

Tags: probability-or-statistics, variational-calculus, functional

I am reading the article of [Deriving probability distributions using the Principle of Maximum Entropy](https://sgfin.github.io/2017/03/16/Deriving-probability-distributions-using-the-Principle-of-Maximum-Entropy/)

and I am trying to derive some of the equations in it automatically using Mathematica.

> ## 1. Derivation of maximum entropy probability distribution with no other constraints (uniform distribution)
>
> First, we solve for the case
> where the only constraint is that the distribution is a pdf, which we
> will see is the uniform distribution. To maximize entropy, we want to
> minimize the following function: $$ J(p)=\int_a^b p(x) \ln p(x) d
>  x-\lambda_0\left(\int_a^b p(x) d x-1\right) $$ . Taking the derivative
> with respect ot $p(x)$ and setting to zero, $$ \frac{\delta J}{\delta
> p(x)}=1+\ln p(x)-\lambda_0=0  $$

Can I derive the second equation automatically using Mathematica?

if just $ J(p)=\int_a^b p(x) \ln p(x) dx$, I can do

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
VariationalD[p[x] Log[p[x]], p[x], x]
```

the output is `1 + Log[p[x]]` as expected.

But here $ J(p)=\int_a^b p(x) \ln p(x) d
 x-\lambda_0\left(\int_a^b p(x) d x-1\right) $, how can I do that?

Comment: Why not `VariationalD[p[x] Log[p[x]] - λ0 ( p[x] - 1), p[x], x]`? What's the issue?

Comment: @bmf: This returns the input in 13.2 on Windows 10. Did you try your suggestion before having posted it?

Comment: @user64494 that's weird. on my laptop it returns `1 - λ0 + Log[p[x]]` which is the expected answer from the OP

Comment: @bmf's code works as expected also in 12.3.1 (Windows) and 13.2.0 (Wolfram Cloud).

Comment: @bmf Thanks, I am not sure `Inegrate[p[x] Log[p[x]] - \[Lambda]0 (p[x] - 1)] === 
 Inegrate[p[x] Log[p[x]]] - \[Lambda]0*(Inegrate[p[x]] - 1)`, the output is False

Comment: @benjaminchanming firstly `Integrate` and also with respect to what? And also, this last comment contradicts what you wrote in the OP in my opinion

Comment: @bmf: Now it produces `1-\[Lambda]0+Log[p[x]]` and  a warning.

Comment: @bmf By the way, Can I use Mathematica to automatically transform J(p) into the form `Integrate[f[x]]`, to get the expression of `f`, so that I can pass `f` into the first parameter of `VariationalD[f,u[x],x]` ?

Comment: @user64494 with `13.2.0` on macOS I have no warnings; [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmlTL.png)

Comment: @bmf Thanks, I changed it into `Integrate[p[x] Log[p[x]] - \[Lambda]0 (p[x] - 1), x] === 
 Integrate[p[x] Log[p[x]], x] - \[Lambda]0*(Integrate[p[x], x] - 1)`, but it still return False. And why the comment contradicts what I wrote in the OP?

Comment: @benjaminchanming I mean that you wrote that if $J$ has the simple form you know how to do the variational derivative in Mathematica. For the complicated form I am unsure why you got stuck, but I showed you that you can write the same command effectively and get the result that you want for $\tfrac{\delta J}{\delta \rho}$ and now you say you are unsure about the result, which is the one you wanted. Unless, I am missing something

Comment: @bmf Thanks! Thanks! Sorry I am not good at calculus. So that I am not sure that the $\int_a^b$ can be factored out to transform 

$$
 \int_a^b p(x) \ln p(x) d
 x-\lambda_0\left(\int_a^b p(x) d x-1\right) 
$$

into 
$$
 \int_a^b (p(x) \ln p(x)-\lambda_0\left( p(x)-1\right))dx 
$$

By which rule in calculus can we do the factoring out $\int_a^b $ transformation?

Comment: @benjaminchanming, [linearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Linearity) is one of the basic properties of integral, and the equality holds (if both of the integrals exist). However, for ill-behaved (!!) functions, the equality might not hold, and that is why Mathematica [returns False](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/why-arent-these-additions-of-integrals-and-summations-equal).

Comment: @Domen Thanks! Now I understand. By the way, Is there a built-in function in Mathematica that can do the factor-out transformation automatically for me?

Comment: @benjaminchanming you can write a rule for yourself and apply the rule if you want :)

Comment: @bmf Thanks! I will try it.